# How to get two fields, side by side in relative layout (android)?

Tags: android, layout

I know that you can use weight parameters for linear layout in order to make two fields align nicely. What I want to do is I want to make sure that left half of the screen is used by one text field and other half is used by other text field (I am talking about width).
How to do so?

Comment: Have you read the documentation and tutorials for RelativeLayout?

Comment: I have been googling / reading about possible and clever answers for almost two hours now...

Comment: Please provide the xml code of this layout to get better answers.

Comment: There is no layout... How can I provide xml layout, if I am trying to figure out how to make one?

Comment: Why do you need to use RelativeLayout in the first place? Why not just use LinearLaouts and set the widths with layout weights?

Answer (score 10):

Use a "hidden view", with no height or width, in the center and put the text views on either side.  Use parent align to set left and right.

```
<RelativeLayout 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <View android:id="@+id/dummy"
       android:layout_height="0dp" 
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

   <TextView
       android:layout_alignRight="@id/dummy"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

   <TextView
       android:layout_alignLeft="@id/dummy"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you calculate width dynamically? Maybe you could use 2 RelativeLayouts in a horizontal LinearLayout?

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible with RelativeLayour as a parent. You need to wrap these TextViews inside a LinearLayout and set the widths with layout weight.

Comment: What about support libraries? Would you recommend using them in order to use grid layout? I want to make sure that my application is compatible with android 2.1

Comment: @user3178137 As you wish ;)