# RelativeLayout - align items center relatively to eachother

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to align two items next to eachother using a `RelativeLayout`, where the vertical center of both items are equal.

For example, if I want this layout:

```
****
**** *******
****

************
```

I'd build something like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View 
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:toRightOf="@id/view1"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/view1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

However, the only options I seem to have is `alignBottom`, `alignTop` and `alignBaseline`. Neither obviously give the desired effect.

Is it possible to get the vertical center of `view2` to match the vertical center of `view1` **without** using a nested layout?

Comment: Did you try considering a table layout

Comment: Of course, there are other viewgroups which might accomplish this. However, I'd like to keep my hierarchy *as flat as possible*. I believe `TableLayout` adds to extra layers.

Comment: Are view2 and view1 the same vertical size? If not, can they be?

Comment: @Matt both are in reality custom views with a height of `wrap_content`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using android:gravity="centerVertical" as an attribute in your RelativeLayout. This should center your child views in the vertical center of the RelativeLayout.

You can also try android:layout_centerVertical="true" as an attribute of the two Views that you want to align.

However, the best solution for this would probably be to create a custom ViewGroup. Then in onLayout of your custom ViewGroup, position your child Views exactly as meets your specifications.

Comment: However, I *don't* want the items to be centered in the parent. I want them to be centered *relatively to each other*.

Comment: Well centering them in the parent will center them relative to each other as well, I believe. But what you may want to try then is enclosing the children you want to center in another ViewGroup (a LinearLayout or another RelativeLayout) which centers the views in that new parent using one of the methods I mentioned. Then you can move that new ViewGroup around as you please in its parent.

Comment: Of course, there are other viewgroups which might accomplish this. However, I'd like to keep my hierarchy as flat as possible.

Comment: Cool, I'm with you there. If you haven't tried using the two methods I mentioned in my answer I'd suggest just seeing how they look. The other thing that might be helpful is if you describe what the views actually contain. If they are text you could make them both 100 dp high and then set the Views' gravity to centerVertical. Are you just drawing lines?

Comment: In reality, the two views are custom views with a height of `wrap_content`. Unfortunately, that makes it not so easy to match the height of the views. I like the thought about using the view's gravity though, not sure if it's usable.

Comment: You know, you could also make a custom ViewGroup specifically for this case. Then in onLayout you could just specifically place your other custom views so that they meet your alignment requirements.

Comment: I guess that would be the best solution indeed. `RelativeLayout` does not seem to support this. If you could add this conclusion to your answer I can accept it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar, where the easiest "hack" was to create an invisible view, place it where ever I wanted, and then placed item A to the left of and item B to the right of this invisible view.

I originally got this idea from Stackoverflow, but don't have the link I used.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21369145/3241079) discusses the same idea.

Comment: Unfortunately, this results in the views having equal width, not aligning their vertical centers.